# Найти подряд идущие дубликаты используя регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, match

Есть к примеру строка, в которой находятся два одинаковых символа. И никак не могу понять, как регулярные выражения их находят.

Вот к примеру такая строка:
`овопы0ais..--.232.s-d-k`

Если написать такую регулярку:
`/([\-])(.*)/i`

То результат будет таким:
`--.232.s-d-k`

Но если строка будет такой:
`овопы0ais..-.232.s-d-k`

При той же регулярке, результат будет таким:
`-.232.s-d-k`

Изначально, я пытался определить дубликаты символов, используя такое решение:
`str.match( /([\-])(.*)/i ).length != 2`

Но если в строке будет присутствовать 2 одинаковых символа, которые находятся в разных местах строки, результат будет всегда положительным.

Подскажите, как все-таки определить дубликаты символов?

Comment: Ничего что ни в одна из приведённых регулярок даже близко не стояла к чему-то, связанному с одинаковыми символами?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если вы хотите обнаружить в строке повтор любого символа (кроме перевода строки), то используете

```
/(.)\1/
```

тут: `(.)` - захват одного символа в группу номер 1 (в данном случае) и `\1` - проверка, что дальше снова идет этот же символ (а точнее группа номер 1).

Если вы хотите проверить список символов на повтор, то используете

```
/([+=.-])\1/
```

где `[+=.-]` перечисление нужных символов (в данном случае `+`, `=`, `.` и `-`).

Если вы хотите проверить конкретный символ на повтор, то используете

```
/\-{2}/
```

тут `\-` символ *черточка* (заэкранированный) и `{2}` - идет два раза подряд.

Comment: То что надо.
Большое спасибо.
Особенно порадовал вариант `\1`. Не знал, что так можно.
Так же вариант с `/\-{2}/` очень хорош.

Comment: @johndws Только `/-{2}/` надо писать, без слеша перед дефисом.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew обязательно запомню

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а там разве будет разница?

Comment: @Grundy Тут не будет. Но в некоторых случаях могут появиться проблемы (например, в [`<input type="text" pattern="\d+\-\d+\-\d+">`](https://jsfiddle.net/4cpcm2yn/)). Так что лучше экранировать только то, что нужно, а не что попало.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, какой движок регулярок используется в html pattern и на сколько он глюковатый? Пример на js с аналогичным глюком заэранированного символа существует? P.S. Всегда считал что `-` спецсимвол в регулярках :)

Comment: @Visman :) А он не глюковатый, просто это такой эффект при использовании модификатора `u` в `RegExp` (ES6), он-то и используется в `pattern`. А `-` специальный только внутри символьного класса. И в шаблонах Lua, там он модификатор идентичный `*?`.

Answer (score 7):

([-]) Находит первое упоминание знака "-", а дальше (.*) берет всю остальную часть строки после него.

Не совсем поняла цель, которую преследует автор. В любом случае, понять регулярные выражения и как они работают очень помогает: https://regexr.com